# Call a function containing AJAX get based on current pathname

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I created a JavaScript function that uses AJAX to call a CodeIgniter controller function that calls the model and retrieves data from the database and is returned as json.

I have successfully created it and have the data rendered using jQuery Template plugin, but I encounter errors when I move the View which renders the data from the index() function into a different function.

ajax goes into error and gives the status of 200.

below is the code:

```
<?php
class Scheduler extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Scheduler_model');
}

public function index() {

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('Rooms_view'); //data appears/gets rendered here
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

}
public function rooms() {

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('Rooms_view'); //error is encountered here
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

}
public function read($table) {
    echo json_encode( $this->Scheduler_model->getAll($table) );
}
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
var readUrl   = 'scheduler/read',
    createUrl = 'scheduler/create',
    updateUrl = 'scheduler/edit',
    delUrl    = 'scheduler/delete',
    delHref,
    delId,
    updateHref,
    updateId;
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    if (pathname == '/MobileSchedule/scheduler/rooms'){ read('rooms');  }
    //if i call read("rooms") here, it appears on index(), but errors on rooms()
}); //end Document ready

function read(table) {
$( '#ajaxLoader' ).fadeIn( 'slow' );

$.ajax({
    url: readUrl + '/' + table,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( response ) {
        for( var i in response ) {
            response[ i ].updateLink = updateUrl + '/' + response[ i ].id;
            response[ i ].deleteLink = delUrl + '/' + response[ i ].id;
        }

        //clear old rows
        $( '.roomsList' ).html( '' );

        //append new rows
        $( '#roomsTemplate' ).render( response ).appendTo( '.roomsList' );

        $( '#ajaxLoader' ).fadeOut( 'slow' );
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(thrownError);
    }

});
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? Use  the network tab in inspect element to see what the HTTP request is sending/receiving, it'll aid in debugging

Comment: on the console.log(xhr) - it has a readyState of 4, status of 200, and responseText is equal to the whole header, rooms_view and footer View files.

for the thrownError log - message = "Unexpected token <"

Comment: I looked intot he Network tab and found that the "rooms" has a path of "/MoibileSchedule/scheduler/scheduler/read". It is only supposed to be "/MoibileSchedule/scheduler/read". 

since rooms() function is in the url scheduler/rooms, i no longer need to add the "scheduler" on the url.

what i did was
    var pathname = window.location.pathname.split('/')[3];
    if (pathname) {
        readUrl = 'read';
    }

Comment: Great! Glad you solved it